# Performance difference in AWS S3 TransferManager multipart upload time when uploading file upload vs InputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, awss3transfermanager, aws-sdk-java

I am using AWS SDK for java. Is there any difference in performance when passing `InputStream` instead of `File` in uploading to AWS S3 using `TransferManager` multipart upload? Should one be preferred over the other or is it just a matter of choice?

Update: In my tests, I found that using an input stream was always slower than using a file. [File Size is 512MB]

P.S.  I am using Spring so what I get is a `MultipartFile` the contents of which I store in the temp file just for uploading to S3.

Answer (score -1):

Faiz you can yuse Amplify SDK for S3 file upload. It's really fast for upload and download files instead of TransferManagerUtils.

ref : https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/android/

Comment: Any benchmarks available?